# Reliable check if a variable exists in R

Tags: r, error-handling, exists, defined

How can I check if something exists or is defined reliably in R? I have a matrix (called `the_matrix`) like so:

```
#Structure of the matrix
    row.names   V1  V2  V3
1   22936   22936   3134    1222
2   285855  285855  5123    1184
3   10409   10409   2857    1142
4   6556    6556    1802    1089

#Get values from the matrix
z=the_matrix['22936',3]
#z equals 1222
z_prime=the_matrix['rowname_not_inmatrix',3]
#returns an error:
#Error in the_matrix["rowname_not_inmatrix", 3] : subscript out of bounds
#(z_prime remains not defined)
```

How can I first check as to whether the value I wish to retrieve from the matrix is defined, rather than just returning an error?

Comment: a "value" cannot be "defined", you can check if a variable exists with `exists(the_matrix)` or if a row name exists with `'rowname_not_inmatrix' %in% rownames(matrix)`, or deal further with errors using `tryCatch` : `tryCatch(the_matrix['rowname_not_inmatrix',3]
,error = function(e) message("nope"))`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I figured it out. It is a wrapper around try, which is itself a wrapper for tryCatch. Here is the function:

```
#this tries to evaluate the expression and returns it, but if it does not work, returns the alternative value. It is simply a wrapper for trycatch. 
#This is similar to python's try except
#e.g.
#the_value=tryExcept(the_matrix[[1]][i,3],0)
#This will return the value of  the_matrix [[1]][i,3], unless it does not exist, in which case it will return zero

tryExcept <- function(expr,alternative)
{
    tryCatch(expr,error=function(e) alternative)
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Use the `%in%` operator along with `row.names` like so:

```
rowname_to_check <- 'rowname_not_inmatrix'
if (rowname_to_check %in% row.names(the_matrix)) {
  z_prime=the_matrix[rowname_to_check,3]
}
```